# How to scale websocket horizontally in websocket-sharp in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

We have requirement, where I need to scale the websocket service to scale to N nodes.

I'm using websocket-sharp library in .Net 4.8.

Mostly i could able to find the solutions to javascript, but I need the solution for .Net.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way for all of your web-socket servers to stay in sync with each other. Once you have multiple servers and a load-balancer your devices are going to be connecting to different servers. One way to accomplish keeping everything in sync is to use a pub / sub (Possibly Redis pub / sub)

1. First your device should connect to a server (in the example below it connects to Server 2)
2. Each server needs to keep a unique list of its connected devices
3. Another device connects and sends data (Because of the load balancer it will most likely connect to a different server than the previous device, new device connects to server 1 in the example below)
4. Server 1 then sends a Pub to Redis to let each server receive a Sub.
5. The Pub / Sub message should contain the unique ID of the device it wishes to send data or a response to.
6. Each server checks its unique list of connected devices to see if it is the server with the requested connected device
7. If the server is the responsible server then it send out a message to the desired device.

[image]

Comment: How is it connecting? via http? ws conenction?
How is data send back from servers? ws connection? Load Balancer is holding ws connections? Because I'm trying to use k8s Load Balancer and its not holding ws conenction so I cannot send date fro mserver to clients.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details on the problem at hand? Do different web-socket connections that could be connected to different web-socket servers need to interact with each other? Scaling horizontally is most likely a language agnostic problem.

Comment: We have thousands of devices are connecting via websocket and sending us the telemetry data, now we are facing the performance issues. We have to increase the nodes of websocket server but the problem is when we try to send the message from server to device it will be sent only if the device is connected to exact node which is broadcasting the message.